# Undefined error when passing data to components

Tags: reactjs

I have two components and I want to passing data to components from the other components. I'm trying with this code but I'm getting this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')**

And it is sending the data but it is sending empty. How can I solve this?

**front.layout.js**

```
import Profile from '../../Views/profile'

const [user, setUser] = useState({});

 return (
    <>
       <Profile values={user} />
    </>
 )
```

**index.js**

```
import Layout from "../../Components/layouts/front.layout";

const Profile = (props) => {
    const { params } = props.match;
    .
    . 
    .
}
```

Comment: console.log(props.user) inside profile component.

Comment: Reading errors is a good habit to get into early. The error is telling you it can't read the name `params` from an undefined value. You're reading from `props.match` but you don't pass in anything named `match`, so it is `undefined`. It's unclear why you pass in "values" and then read "props.match.params" - you may want to read up on how react props work

Comment: It works when I'm not trying to pass data, that is, when I don't type `<Profile values={user} />`, but I have to use this because I want to pass data to the other component.

Comment: @AndyRay, I had the same thought, but `props.match` is a routing method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to note here:

The following initiates `user` with an empty object, so you can not destructure from it.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
```

Then, you're passing props called `values`, with the value of `user`.

So in your container, you can set the default value for params.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({ params: {} });
```

Then in your component you can destructure it (from `prop.values`)

```
const Profile = (props) => {
    const { params } = props.values;
    .
    . 
    .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You neee to wrap this component with withRouter () function
This one you can import like that:

```
import {withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';



export default withRouter (component-name);
```